# Java - collection and array tables

Tags: java

i have a little task in java generated from an exercise randomizer application. The instructions are:

Write a class named Vulgarist with a public identifier which must contain a public static method mes. This method gets as arguments a Vector type collection of Long and two tables with
boolean type elements. The two tables and the collection have the
same number of elements.
The method returns  as a result a Vector type collection of 
Long consisting of the elements of the collection of the first argument
for which the corresponding element of the first table is the value
true and the corresponding element of the second table is
the value false.

My code is:

```
import java.util.Vector;
public class Vulgarist {
    public static Vector<Long> mes(Vector<Long> v1, boolean a[], boolean b[]) {
        Vector<Long> v2 = new Vector<>();
        while ((v1.size() == b.length) && (v1.size() == a.length)
            && (a.length == b.length)) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
                if ((a[i] == true) && (b[i] == false)) {
                    v2.add(v1.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        return v2;
    }
}
```

The result i get from the application is "The method mes was not implemented according to the instructions"
Message Error : null

Can anyone help me find what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main problems:

1. Your `while` loop is unnecessary, and will always evaluate to `true`, thus resulting in an endless loop.  Just remove the `while` loop.  It doesn't accomplish anything.
2. The `for` condition `i <= a.length` should be changed to `i < a.length` to avoid getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Remember that the last available index on an array is `length - 1`.

Comment: Wow at first i had no while loop and added it later cause i thought that it was the reason of my problem. Turns out, all this time the problem was in the for as u correctly suggested. Such a small thing. Thank you.